# Export Signing Certificate without Xcode

Tags: macos, terminal, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I've suggessfully requested and installed the certificate to sign our OS X applications by double-clicking the `.cer` file. Signing works fine with

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application" MyApp.app
```

Now I want to export the certificate and belonging private/public keys to import it on a different OS X version of the same machine. Unfortunately, the documentation on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW1/) seems to only describe exporting/importing from Xcode which I don't have and don't want to install. What other ways there are to export the keys and certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Keychain Access`.

(`Finder` > `Utilities` > `Keychain Access`)

Comment: Sure, but which one to export? I have multiple equally named entries there.